# how to find Marginal probability function for Piecewise joint probability density

Tags: probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

Given the following joint density function:

$$ \displaystyle
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0.5 & \text{if  $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{3}, \> \frac{1}{3} \leq y < 1, $} \\
0.75 & \text{if  $\frac{1}{3} \leq x < \frac{2}{3}, \> \frac{1}{3} \leq y < 1, $} \\
0.25 & \text{if  $\frac{2}{3} \leq x < 1, \> \frac{1}{3} \leq y < 1, $} \\
2 & \text{if  $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{3}, \> 0 \leq y < \frac{1}{3}, $} \\
3 & \text{if  $\frac{1}{3} \leq x < \frac{2}{3}, \> 0 \leq y < \frac{1}{3}, $} \\
1 & \text{if  $\frac{2}{3} \leq x < 1, \> 0 \leq y < \frac{1}{3}, $} \\
\end{cases}
$$

The marginal probability is

$$ f_X(x)=\int_{y} f(x,y)dy \\f_Y(y)=\int_{x} f(x,y)dx $$

But if $f(x,y)$ has multiple values for a given $x,y$, how do you evaluate the integral?

Comment: You would effectively do it case by case.

Comment: So for example, I'd assume 0<=y<=1/3, and evaluate over dx? In that case though, wouldn't it be three integrals of length 1/3, times 2+3+1, which gives me f_Y(y)= 1/3*(6)=2; But shouldn't the probability be less than 1? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: A probability **density** function (which $f_Y$ is) is allowed to take values greater than 1! But yes, that is how you'd find $f_Y(y)$ for $0\le y\le 1/3$. You then need to separately find $f_Y(y)$ for $1/3 \le y \le 1$.

Comment: shoot..you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get you "on the road" I will provide one of the cases.

Let it be that $\frac13\leq x<\frac23$.

Then:$$f_{X}\left(x\right)=\int f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)\;dy=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)\;dy+\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{1}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)\;dy=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}3\;dy+\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{1}0.75\;dy=$$$$\left[3y\right]_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left[0.75y\right]_{\frac{1}{3}}^{1}=3\left(\frac{1}{3}-0\right)+0.75\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)=1.5$$